# Is it safe to mark prop-types as peer dependency in your react module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-proptypes

How can I export my component's `propTypes` so when I include this package in my project, IDE can suggest them without affecting my bundle size ?

Or how the user may be able to get rid of them ?

Is it safe to mark `prop-types` as `peeDependency` since react includes it ?

I use `rollup@1.27.13` and `@babel/core@7.7.7` and few other plugins for each of them.

When I remove propTypes using the code bellow, my bundle size is 1.58kb gzipped

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": false
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-remove-prop-types", {
      "removeImport": true
    }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
  ]
}
```

But when I leave them (and then I can get suggestions by IDE) it jumps to 6.45kb gzipped.

rollup config:

```
{
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    terser()
  ],
}
```

Thanks